# How to set dynamic CSS property values in React and copy stylesheet content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, stylesheet

I'm attempting to build something similar to [this tool](http://k88hudson.github.io/syntax-highlighting-theme-generator/www/).

When the user changes the color, the hex value is updated and the specific CSS property value associated with the given CSS rule is updated. The updated value is set dynamically and changes the syntax highlight color in the displayed Markdown.

I dug into the authors code to get a rough idea and found she was using LESS for styles and an older version of React and I was thrown off. The stylesheet that's associated with updating the colors is different than the main styles for the page. It only contains styles for syntax highlighting in Prism.js.

My issues are the following.

1. How do I access CSS property values in a stylesheet and change them dynamically based on user input?
2. How do I serve the stylesheet to the user after new colors have been set? I'm attempting to have a copy button that will simply copy the entire CSS stylesheet to the clipboard so the user can then use said styles.

I was thinking that I could use the CSSStyleDeclaration interface and the setProperty() method by having the value in the method be a template literal and change it dynamically based on the input value of the hex color chosen.

I'm sure there's a more obvious approach to this, but it's not hitting me. All help is appreciated.

Comment: A good tool to use for this is [`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components).

Comment: I'm currently using styled-components for the entire page, but I'm not sure how I'd extract a stylesheet from it to serve to the user.